# What's a good alternative to cascading checkboxes?

Tags: forms, checkboxes, lists

We have a web interface for running a report. The report can be pretty complex. There are various topics that can be included in the report, and each topic has sub-topics.

Right now, the interface is implemented with a list of checkboxes. It looks like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFv2je.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

When you check a checkbox to select that topic, more checkboxes appear below the parent checkbox for the subtopics:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVUZoy.png)</sup>

We're looking to redesign this because when you select a checkbox, it pushes all the other checkboxes down and out of view. We have thought about making the checkboxes collapsible, but one of the benefits of the current implementation is it lets you see ALL of the checkboxes you have selected. If the checkboxes became collapsible, it would be harder to view everything that has been selected. Any recommendations for an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could initially just have the user select from the list of main checkboxes.  Once they've chosen the boxes, they can press select to go to a list that contains the sub-topics.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDI8pk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

and then once the user finishes selecting the main topics....

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnxur.png)</sup>

This design will fulfill both of your requirements:

1. to see all of the main topics that are selected at the same time.  (Because they do not expand, you can quickly select all of interest.)
2. still to see all of the topics that they have selected.  (The second stage lists all of the subtopics together, so the user can see everything they've selected, rather than displaying subtopics one topic at a time.)

Answer (score 5):

2 propositions

First one will work depending on the lenght of the text and the quantity of subtopics but *it lets you see ALL of the checkboxes you have selected*

[image]

The idea is that you uncheck what you do not want instead of checking it.

Second will work in any case, but will be less transparent

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the concept of collapsible checkboxes as that is a affordance which has become pretty common with the use of file explorers which allow users to expand and collapse sections as needed.

[image]

If you need to show the items which are selected, You can show the items which are only selected while hiding the rest as shown below

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1tjNq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I don't really see how this is any different then what I originally had. It also has the same problem as my original design where checkboxes gets pushed down as you check more checkboxes.